# Print Unique output using "uniq" bash skipping first n characters

Tags: linux, bash, macos

So I am trying to print a unique output using the "uinq" utility in bash but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my file which has the following content in it:-

```
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd89f794bc0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "lspcidrv.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.evosx86.driver.lspcidrv" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a1646250 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "ACPIPoller.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.rehabman.driver.ACPIPoller" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a1639640 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "ACPIBatteryManager.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd89f68ec60 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "USBInjectAll.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.rehabman.driver.USBInjectAll" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a1624500 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "RealtekRTL8111.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.insanelymac.RealtekRTL8111" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67054) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a14f00c0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "X86PlatformPlugin.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/", ID = "com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a15b45f0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_LPCSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.LPCSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a15a5f10 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.netkas.driver.FakeSMC" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a15b2030 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_CPUSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.CPUSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a15ab6d0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_ACPISensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.ACPISensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a159bfb0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.driver.FakePCIID" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a159f440 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID_Intel_HDMI_Audio.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.injector.FakePCIID-Intel-HDMI-Audio" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a159e910 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID_Intel_HD_Graphics.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.injector.FakePCIID-Intel-HD-Graphics" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a15480e0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "CodecCommander.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.tw.CodecCommander" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fd8a153eee0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "AsusNBFnKeys.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.emlydinesh.driver.AsusNBFnKeys" }
KernelCache ID: A297C9A0448F4369BE17FFCFB1682182
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc8528c4d0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "AsusNBFnKeys.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.emlydinesh.driver.AsusNBFnKeys" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc8528cc30 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "CodecCommander.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.tw.CodecCommander" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852b3b10 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.driver.FakePCIID" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852b24f0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID_Intel_HD_Graphics.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.injector.FakePCIID-Intel-HD-Graphics" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852b4a40 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID_Intel_HDMI_Audio.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.injector.FakePCIID-Intel-HDMI-Audio" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852bb520 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.netkas.driver.FakeSMC" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852c0ce0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_ACPISensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.ACPISensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852c7640 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_CPUSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.CPUSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc852c74e0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_GPUSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.GPUSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc853f4af0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_LPCSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.LPCSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67054) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc8516ea40 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "X86PlatformPlugin.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/", ID = "com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc857cb360 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "RealtekRTL8111.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.insanelymac.RealtekRTL8111" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc85432aa0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "USBInjectAll.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.rehabman.driver.USBInjectAll" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc82d049c0 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "ACPIBatteryManager.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc851c2520 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "ACPIPoller.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.rehabman.driver.ACPIPoller" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext 0x7fdc851f3f90 [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "lspcidrv.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.evosx86.driver.lspcidrv" }
```

As you might have noticed except for the 8th field, every "kext" has one redundant entry. I have tried using `cat myfile | uniq -f8` but that doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: You mean you want to show unique lines but ignoring the first field after `OSKext`?

Comment: Note that `uniq` doesn't promise that it'll work with unsorted inputs. (This lack-of-guarantee lets it work in constant memory). You need to either sort on that field, or use a different tool (`awk` is common).

Comment: @lurker Exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uniq` requires its input to be sorted. Fulfilling that, as in the following:

```
sed -E -e 's/OSKext 0x[^[:space:]]+ /OSKext ELIDED /g' | sort | uniq
```

...yields, with your input on stdin:

```
KernelCache ID: A297C9A0448F4369BE17FFCFB1682182
Kext with invalid signatured (-67054) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "X86PlatformPlugin.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/", ID = "com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "ACPIBatteryManager.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "ACPIPoller.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.rehabman.driver.ACPIPoller" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "AsusNBFnKeys.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.emlydinesh.driver.AsusNBFnKeys" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "CodecCommander.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.tw.CodecCommander" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.driver.FakePCIID" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID_Intel_HDMI_Audio.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.injector.FakePCIID-Intel-HDMI-Audio" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakePCIID_Intel_HD_Graphics.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.rehabman.injector.FakePCIID-Intel-HD-Graphics" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.netkas.driver.FakeSMC" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_ACPISensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.ACPISensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_CPUSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.CPUSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_GPUSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.GPUSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "FakeSMC_LPCSensors.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "org.hwsensors.driver.LPCSensors" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "RealtekRTL8111.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.insanelymac.RealtekRTL8111" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "USBInjectAll.kext/ -- file:///System/Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.rehabman.driver.USBInjectAll" }
Kext with invalid signatured (-67062) allowed: <OSKext ELIDED [0x7fff9e7e6980]> { URL = "lspcidrv.kext/ -- file:///Library/Extensions/", ID = "com.evosx86.driver.lspcidrv" }
```

Comment: Replacing first field after "OSKext"  with a constant was the key then as I had tried earlier by sorting the output and piping it to uniq.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

without resorting to sorting (pun intended)

```
$ awk '{k=$8; $8=""} !a[$0]++{$8=k; print}' file | wc -l

17
```

print the unique entries modulus 8th field, in the same order of the input file.

if you don't want to preserve the field, it's simpler...

```
$ awk '{$8="REMOVED"} !a[$0]++' file
```